# How to set JTable on JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

This is my Java code. In this code I am trying to add `JTable` on `JFrame` but table does not show on frame what is the problem in my code?

```
    table_1 = new JTable();
    table_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    table_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    table_1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
            },
        new String[] {
            "Last Name", "First Name"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] {
                String.class, String.class
            };
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return columnTypes[columnIndex];
            }
        });
        table_1.setBounds(20, 314, 1254, -74);
        contentPane.add(table_1);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: You don't place a JTable directly on a JFrame.  You place a JTable inside a JScrollPane.  You place the JScrollPane inside a JPanel.  You place the JPanel inside a JFrame.  The Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will show you all the steps to creating a Swing GUI.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to try the code, very incomplete, but I would guess that
 `table_1.setBounds(20, 314, 1254, -74);`  
with a negative height is very *difficult* to display.

It is better not to use the `null` layout manager<sup>**1**</sup>...
check Oracle's [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) tutorial.

Also usual to add the `JTable` to a `JScrollPane`.

<sup>**1** - assumption since missing the corresponding code and using `setBounds`</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Now I have to change the negative value. Then the table is visible but the columns are not.

Comment: You need to add the table into a JScrollPane and the the JScrollpane into the contentPane